# How to use Pagination for xml response in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, pagination

I have a PHP REST webservice. The client-side is PHP and server side is codeigniter.
 The response data or XML is too long so I am thinking of using pagination. I want to list the data in the form of a table with pagination. Is there any possible method for doing pagination in this case?

Will pagination be possible if I convert the whole request XML data to PHP array at the client side?

Comment: Yes you can paginate the `php array`

Comment: @Rohan Kumar : Can you provide links.

Comment: I can't see why it'd be different from paginating a regular listing. What's your exact doubt?

Comment: @Developer I don't try this but the links are http://hub.lotsofcode.com/php-array-pagination/ ,
https://github.com/lotsofcode/php-array-pagination/blob/master/example.php ,
http://everything-php.nuvvo.com/lesson/1355-php-array-pagination ,
 http://www.codehive.net/PHP-Array-Pagination-10.html

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario : I have done pagination in codeigniter. In that the data is fetched from database according to limit of content per page. But here all we have is a xml string.

Comment: Well... I suggest your *decode* the string before you process it :)

Comment: @Rohan Kumar:Thanks for the links.